# Converting IMG tag to AMP-IMG

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm using a `preg_replace` to convert an `<img>` tag to `<amp-img>` but it's not working.

```
$str = '<img src="welcome.jpg" alt="Welcome">';

echo preg_replace("%<img .*>%i", "<amp-img $1></amp-img>", $str);
```

Comment: If you're on a WordPress site, then perhaps [this amp guide](https://wpza.net/how-to-convert-img-to-amp-img-tags-in-wordpress/) might be useful to you. However, the same principle applies to those who aren't on WordPress, as the function helps get the width/height too — which is something missing from your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use (.*) to capture everything in between the space and the >

```
preg_replace("/<img (.*)>/", "<amp-img $1></amp-img>", '<img src="welcome.jpg" alt="Welcome">')
```

should give the result

```
<amp-img src="welcome.jpg" alt="Welcome"></amp-img>
```

Comment: I forgot the brackets :-(